# Transfer file between two csv with php

Tags: php

I tried the code in this way. Now it writes a part of the first csv in the second but i don't understand because it doesn't not copy all.
Why?
// Sopprimo gli errori del php
    //error_reporting(0);

```
// Includo la libreria
require_once 'excel_reader2.php';

$file_handle = fopen("SATconcluse.csv", "r");




while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 0);

    $arr = array('Nr SAT' => $line_of_text[0],'Data Apertura' => $line_of_text[13], 'Tipo Servizio' => $line_of_text[1], 'Stato SAT' => $line_of_text[2],'Marca Terminale' => $line_of_text[4], 'Modello Terminale' => $line_of_text[5], 'IMEI guasto' => $line_of_text[6],'IMEI consegnato' => $line_of_text[7],'Famiglia guasto' => $line_of_text[8],'Descrizione guasto' => $line_of_text[9] );
    $data[] = $arr;
}
fclose($file_handle);
$file = fopen("eccomiquacisono.csv","w");
foreach ($data as $arr){
    fputcsv($file,$arr);
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: What is the problem? You need to ask a more detailed question than just "Someone can help me"…

Comment: "it does not work" is **no** description of the problem

Comment: I do not see where you fill $data.

Comment: I haven't error but the second csv is empy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net//manual/it/function.fgetcsv.php) to load your file in an array, and then carry on with your processing. If you areusing PHP5, you can simply set the second parameter to 0 to get the whole line:

```
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 0);
```

Likewise, use [`fputcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/it/function.fputcsv.php) to save individual records in a CSV file.
In your code, you are trying to fill in a file with an empty array. You probably meant to add each `$arr` in `$data` sequentially:

```
$data[] = $arr;
```

And then loop on each entry and put it in the other file:

```
foreach ($data as $arr)
    fputcsv($file,$arr);
```

The whole code thus would be:

```
$data = array();

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 0);
    $arr = array(...);
    $data[] = $arr;
}
fclose($file_handle);
$file = fopen("eccomiquacisono.csv","w");
foreach ($data as $arr)
    fputcsv($file,$arr);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Is the same thing that i tried to do. My code it doesn't work, so can you show me how i can fix it?

Comment: I don't understand. Please, can you show me ho i have to insert this code in my project? My code is below the question. Thanks

Comment: I tried to insert your code in the my but always doesn't work. Can you insert the code in my project and show me? Please, really i tried but i don't understand !

Comment: Now it works but not correctly. In the csv file it doesn't write all the csv but only a part of the file. Why?

Comment: Really, what is missing?